# Not display "Javascript" item when I create Unity3d script

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine

Hello I'm Unity3D Beginner.
Unity3D can create script C# and Javascript.
But my unity3d only can create C# but not Javascript
[image]

[image]

I want to create Javascript.
Anyone know this problem?

Comment: Unity no longer supports js. https://forum.unity.com/threads/is-unityscript-javascript-discontinued.486824/  Just google something like `unity3d javascript`  first instead of asking on SO without making any attempt yourself.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal It is currently still supported but will be removed in the future. They simply removed the menu that createe new Javascript codes.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal  thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is not supported in Unity3D now. You can not create new JavaScript from Unity3D.

Comment: i give up javascript, thank you !